# How to click randomly with a randomly selected page

Tags: python, selenium, testing, automation, wildcard

I want to click an add to cart button in an ecommerce website, my problem is every item has a different button id. and i notice that the id is located in the div.

i try to select a wild card since every item has a different id.

```
addcart = driver.find_elements_by_css_selector("div[id*=\"addtocart-\"]")
addcart.click()
```

[here is the sample code, i want to click the addtocart-49831, how can i click that button?](https://i.stack.imgur.com/X0AEJ.png)

Comment: Do you mind sharing some line of code for the button? This could help for a better answer

Comment: just added a link thank you

Comment: What does this have to do with random clicks or random pages?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are many other ways to locate element without using it's `@id`:

- By its text:

  ```
  addcart = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//button[.='Add To Cart']")
  ```
- By buttons' type:

  ```
  addcart = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//button[@type='submit']")
  ```
- By class names:

  ```
  driver.find_element_by_css_selector("div.add_to_cart_btn")
  ```

  or

  ```
  driver.find_element_by_class_name("add_to_cart_btn")
  ```

Note that in your code you're using `find_elements...()` to get element and then click it while this method returns a *list* of elements. You need to use `find_element...()` or `find_elements...()[0]` instead

P. S. Let me know if it's not what you want as the title *"click randomly with a randomly selected page"* does not really match the issue description

Comment: yes you answered my question right, sorry for my title. but i have multiple add to cart button in my current page. how to click a specific add to cart button.?

Comment: im getting this error after i tried above codes "driver.find_elements_by_class_name("add_to_cart_btn").click()
AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'click'"

Comment: i now can continue, thank you, i should use element instead of element, im kinda stubborn af, thank you sir big help

Comment: Welcome! You can [accept my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer) if it solved your problem. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Create a list of urls which you want to hit and randomly select one and go to it. Then select the css_selectors and randomly select one to click. Something like this:-

```
driver = webdriver.Firefox()
urls = ['url1','url2','url3']
url = urls[randint(0, len(urls) - 1)]

driver.get(url) # <- This will take you to a random page

current_page = driver.current_url
i=0
while i<10: # <- Create your loop as you want
    try:
        selectors = driver.find_elements_by_css_selector('.content-link.spf-link.yt-uix-sessionlink.spf-link') #<- get the css_selectors

        l = selectors[randint(0, len(selectors) - 1)] #<- Select a random selector

        l.click()
        #  Write your 
        #  code here
    except:
        continue
```